# Levitation with electromotive force

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, levitation

Is it possible to achieve levitation, if you have an electromotive force, with an electrostatic charge? Using a coil, and a sheet of aluminum or something

Comment: You may want to learn about [Earnshaw's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earnshaw%27s_theorem).

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically yes, I don't see what could provent you from levitating using electromagnetism if you have the right configuration. But it is very likely to be too much expensive for the benefit, and also dangerous for you. A human body can be seen as a huge water baloon, and as water is a very good conductor and you would need to use a very large amount of electricity for your experiment, the risk is obvious. You would also need to consider the risk of [electrical breakdown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_breakdown) since you would have to use a very high voltage.

So my advice would be to find another way to levitate (-:

Answer (score -1):

It is possible to use an electrostatic charge to levitate and move objects in a controlled setting with low risk for humans.

The largest object I succeeded in levitating at the moment is 120 height and 150 mm in diameter. with 0.77 watt.

You need a high-voltage power supply with current limiting.

It is the lowest cost for levitating with propulsion.

There is no existing system that has wireless energy transfer with propulsion and self-calibrating except
see; Quasi antigravity levitation and propulsion.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Awe_NeibTM